# javascript url call executing twice

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to show this json data in a javascript alert box, but it shows it twice (same content). It is working, but I do not know why it is displaying two alerts.
(javascript is not my preferred language).

This is the response from the URL called:

```
{
  "type": "error",
  "response": {
    "message": "Could not start app"
  }
}
```

This is the code I am using:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
       
        function call() {
            const Http = new XMLHttpRequest();
            const url='https://url_to_get_the_response';
            Http.open("GET", url);
            Http.send();
            Http.onreadystatechange = (e) => {
                if (Http.responseText) {
                alert(Http.responseText);
               }
           }
    }
    </script>
```

And I get two alerts, both containing the same thing (the .json result). I only want one of them.

I have tried adding a `return;` and `break call;` in the `if (Http.responseText)` section. Adding the `return;` in the `if` statement didn't do anything and adding the `break call;` stopped it working.

Any advice on this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You approach is correct. `onreadystatechange` event is triggered multiple times, as the `readyState` attribute changes from the beginning to the end of an API call.

On adding if condition for the appropriate `readyState`  and `status` value that comes in the `XMLHttpRequest` Object. Solves this issue.

You can read more about those attributes here  [readyState](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/readyState), [status](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/status)

```js
function call() {
        const Http = new XMLHttpRequest();
        const url='https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1';
        Http.open("GET", url);
        Http.send();
        Http.onreadystatechange = (e) => {
            if (Http.readyState == 4 && Http.status == 200 && Http.responseText) {
            alert(Http.responseText);
           }
       }
  }
```

```html
<button onclick='call()'>Call</button>
```